Vanishing of Ext involving unipotent group schemes and $\mathbb{G}_m$
I am currently reading Serre's Algebraic Groups and Class Fields. In chapter 8.1.6, Prop. 7 says that if $A$ and $B$ are linear algebraic groups then $H^2_{reg}(A,B)_s=Ext(A,B)$. The definition of  $H^2_{reg}(A,B)_s$ is not really relevant for this question.
He uses the fact that every connected linear group is the product of an unipotent group with some groups $\mathbb{G}_m$. The proof then uses the vanishing of the following Ext groups to conlcude the result.
So my question is why exactly are the groups; $Ext(\mathbb{G}_m,U )$ and  $Ext(\mathbb{G}_m,\mathbb{G}_m)$ trivial?
